# outgoing call detect in PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, listener, telephonymanager

I want to detect outgoing call in android application . Actually I can detect outgoing calls but it is also working for incoming too and I don't want that. I need it to work only for outgoing. here is my code....

```
boolean ringing = false;
boolean offhook = false;

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

   switch (state) {


    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

 if((!ringing)&& offhook){
              ///incomming call
         }
          break;
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

    callerPhoneNumber = incomingNumber;
 Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
 ringing = true;
 offhook = false;     
 break;

   case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

 Log.d(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
 offhook = true;
 ringing = false;
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`.

[See here](http://www.krvarma.com/posts/android/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/) Sample code is available

Comment: Thanks a lot....but how can i start and stop broadcast receiver . that is wahy i am using service and implementing phonestatelistener in service and here i don't have option to detect outgoing call.

Comment: I had write broadcast receiver but it detects only outgoing call connect and outgoing call reject. I also want to check whether the call is to connect or not like listen busy tone user speaks to someone else.

Comment: The  link to the blog here is dead