# Does call logs register the sim serial number from which the calls where made from?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am creating an application on call logs and I stumbled onto this idea. Now calls made from phone dialler and those made from voip software installed on the device also comes up as call logs and am guessing because the Voip software calls the phone dialler when ever the call button is push on the Voip. Now I am thinking of a solution to eliminate the voip calls and I came up with this idea but I dont know if it is feasible.

Now is it possible to get the Sim card serial number from which a specific call was made from or with?

Here is  the code line I am using.

```
        Telly=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    simSerialNumber=Telly.getSimSerialNumber();
    Cursor Logs_query=managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number=Logs_query.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
```

I would appreciate some help in suggestions and codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now is it possible to get the Sim card serial number from which a specific call was made from or with?

No, you cannot differentiate the logs are from which dialler.

The call log content provider does not save the information of the dialler that insert the log.

Comment: Ok. But do you think it is possible for me to create a PhoneCall Listener to register outgoing calls each time a call is made and then store/ save the call logs and the sim serial number maybe in a database?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to monitor outgoing & incoming call. (Got quite a number of good examples in StackOverFlow) -> The problem I see in this approach is, what if the user install your app after he has make tons of VoIP call? All those are still recorded and you won't know.

Comment: Yes you are right but there would be a restriction to only get calls from the day the app was installed. Please can you add a link of the good examples you are talking about? I seem not to be getting any from my search.

Comment: Ya, sure. In short, you will be dealing with TelephonyManager. Examples: [Outgoing Monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377933/outgoing-call-detect-in-phonestatelistener) and [Incoming Monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036295/not-able-to-get-the-telephonymanager-call-state-ringing)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any results now or exceptions if you run that code? 
And have you set the permission `READ_PHONE_STATE`? This is needed to use the `getSimSerialNumber()` method.

Comment: Yes I have set the READ_PHONE_STATE and I get the sim serial Number quite alright. But what I want is that for every calls made with a particular sim card does it register the sim serial number or is there anyway to know which sim serial number a call was made from?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Telephony Manager;If at all you not found the contact no. of user; You can get Sim Serial Number of Sim Card and Imei No. of Android Device by using the same Telephony Manager Class...

Add permission:

Import:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

Use the below code:

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

```
     // get IMEI
     imei = tm.getDeviceId();

     // get SimSerialNumber
     simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```